# Centralize Logging configuration for multiple maven artifacts using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Suppose I have 3 maven projects: project1, project2 and project 3. All of them have the following lines in the application.yml (these lines are identical in all projects):

```
logging:
  file.name: ../logs/@project.artifactId@.log
  file.max-size: 20MB
```

As you can see, I am defining just two configurations: the name of the log file and the max size of it. I am also using maven `@project.artifactId@` to define the name of the log file as the maven artifact ID.

What I want is to have another project called `parent-project` that is the parent (in maven) of the other 3 projects. This new project would contain the above logging configuration and in some way (this is the question I am asking) the other 3 projects would inherate this configuration. This means that the log file of each child should be named based on the child artifact ID.

For your information, the pom of the projects (1, 2 and 3) looks like this:

```
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>project1</artifactId>

... 

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>application.yml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: This is not wise. It will create lots of trouble as different copies of `application.yml` conflict. It's better to either make this part of the template you use to generate your projects or to have it configured at runtime by your deployment setup.

Comment: Thank you @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Could you please tell me what kind of troubles this could generate?